# Apply substitution N times

Tags: bash, sed

I have a string like

```
data1_data2_data3_data4@data5,data6
```

It happens that, sometimes, data5 contains underscores, which happens to be the field separator. Ugly, I know.

I want to read this data pieces with something like:

```
IFS="_@," read d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 <<< "$input"
```

The problem arrives when data5 contains an underscore. To work around this issue. I want to substitute the first three underscores with commas (and the @ too). The easies way I found so far is with sed:

```
sed 's/_/,/; s/_/,/; s/_/,/; s/@/,/' <<< "$input"
```

But repeating three times the same substitution seems quite inefficient. What happens if I need to repeat it 5000 times?

Is there any way to tell sed to repeat a substitution a certain amount of times?

To be complete, sample input:

```
input="data1_data2_data3_data4@d_a_t_a_5,data6"
IFS="," read d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 <<< "$input"
```

Expected output:

```
d1=="data1"
d2=="data2"
d3=="data3"
d4=="data4"
d5=="d_a_t_a_5"
d6=="data6"
```

Comment: Hi Poshi. How might we distinguish between the underscores in `data1_data2` and `d_a_t_a_5`. How are the underscores in the latter case specific field-delimited against the surround fields?

Comment: if you are looking for efficiency, avoid using bash read bultin which is slow. what about using perl?

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul this is part of a bigger script, thrwing in perl to parse a string and having to process it anyways in bash would be horrible. Performance does not matter, but that's no reason to throw in perl and go from 0.1s to 0.5s.

Comment: @Poshi do not consider this comment have you seen my answer

Comment: @TrebuchetMS, data{1..4} does not have underscores. Before `@`, underscore is the field separator. After `@`, comma is the field separator.

Comment: @Poshi: But you mentioned in question that `The problem arrives when data4 contains an underscore` so you may have `_` before `@` also that you don't want to split on.

Comment: @anubhava Ouch, right... typo. I'm gonna correct it.

Comment: BTW, data4 could contain underscores and be an identifiable field as long as data{1..3} does not contain underscores. but the problem aroused with data5. Data4 will always be an integer.

Comment: Ideally, fix whatever process or tool produces this infuriating format in the first place.

Comment: Unfortunately, this a kind of ID with several parents. data1 ~ [0-9A-Z]{9}, data2 ~ {1..8}, data3 ~ [a-zA_Z0-9\-.]+, data4 ~ [0-9]+, data5 ~ [a-zA-Z0-9\-._]+, data6 ~ [a-zA-Z0-9\-.]+. Kinda simplified. data5 in particular are IDs that comes from public databases.

Comment: @Poshi: I made a change in my `awk` based on your changes in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk` in a process substitution:

```
input="data1_data2_data3_data4@d_a_t_a_5,data6"

IFS=, read d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 < <(awk -F@ -v OFS=, -v n=3 '{
while (i++<n) sub(/_/, ",", $1)} 1' <<< "$input")

# check variable values
declare -p d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6
```

```
declare -- d1="data1"
declare -- d2="data2"
declare -- d3="data3"
declare -- d4="data4"
declare -- d5="d_a_t_a_5"
declare -- d6="data6"
```

- `awk` command uses `@` as field separator.
- `awk` command replaces `_` with `,` in **1st field only** and **exactly** `n` times.

Comment: This solution is good for the 5000 hypothesis, but it goes far away from the simple-easy-short one-liner I'm looking for. Also, it is not transforming only the first N occurences of underscore, but all until "@", but this can be easily solved. Anyways, your code solves the problem at hand, but is a lot more verbose that just repeating the sed substitution three times :-(

Comment: Hahaha! Good rewrite. I think this is the closer I will get to my Holy Grail. I'm sad that there's no flag to tell the interpreter to repeat the substitution N times and I have to process the fields manually.

Comment: But I do agree with you that it is more verbose that you would have liked :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use awk.

```
$ input="data1_data2_data3_data4@d_a_t_a_5,data6"
$ awk -v RS='[@\n]' '{ if(NR % 2){ gsub(/_/, ","); ORS = "," } else ORS = "\n" } 1' <<< "$input"
data1,data2,data3,data4,d_a_t_a_5,data6
```

Answer (score 0):

an option could be to split manually using shell expansion `${var%%pat}` strips largest suffix matching pat and `${var#pat}` strips shortest prefix matching pat

```
while IFS= read line; do
    tmpline=$line
    d1=${tmpline%%_*} tmpline=${tmpline#*_}
    d2=${tmpline%%_*} tmpline=${tmpline#*_}
    d3=${tmpline%%_*} tmpline=${tmpline#*_}
    d4=${tmpline%%@*} tmpline=${tmpline#*@}
    d5=${tmpline%%,*} tmpline=${tmpline#*,}
    d6=${tmpline}

    printf "%s\n" "d1=$d1" "d2=$d2" "d3=$d3" "d4=$d4" "d5=$d5" "d6=$d6"
done <<< "$input"
```

or to get around bash read slowness, split lines manually

```
tmpinput=$input
while [[ $tmpinput ]]; do
    if [[ $tmpinput = *$'\n'* ]]; then
        tmpline=${tmpinput%%$'\n'*} tmpinput=${tmpinput#*$'\n'}
    else
        tmpline=${tmpinput} tmpinput=''
    fi

    d1=${tmpline%%_*} tmpline=${tmpline#*_}
    d2=${tmpline%%_*} tmpline=${tmpline#*_}
    d3=${tmpline%%_*} tmpline=${tmpline#*_}
    d4=${tmpline%%@*} tmpline=${tmpline#*@}
    d5=${tmpline%%,*} tmpline=${tmpline#*,}
    d6=${tmpline}

    printf "%s\n" "d1=$d1" "d2=$d2" "d3=$d3" "d4=$d4" "d5=$d5" "d6=$d6"
done
```

Comment: "*What happens if I need to repeat it 5000 times?*"

Comment: here it's a quite more efficient than calling sed because expansion is a builtin not spawning a new process, but the bottleneck is read builtin

Comment: Good point for the efficiency consideration, but this is not the point. I'm trying to make the most compact and clear code for the problem at hand. The input will always be a single line, tipically around 40 bytes. It is for interactive work. I'm pretty sure the operator won't worry about having to wait 0.1 seconds more. but I'm worried if some day I have to do something similar with a longest string.

Comment: in your question you asked if you have to repeat 5000 times, the most compact is sed version, the drawback is that you are starting a new process for each call, the same with awk or perl

Comment: Right, this is why I only start a single `sed` process with all the substitutions in there :-)

Comment: maybe i misunderstood 5000 times was on one line i though on 5000 different lines

Answer (score 0):

In `bash`, I would use a regular expression instead.

```
$ cat input
one_two_three_fourpt1_fourpt2@fivept1_fivept2,six
$ regex='([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_(.+)@([^,]+).(.*)'
$ while IFS= read -r line; do
> [[ $line =~ $regex ]]
> done < input
$ printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"
one_two_three_fourpt1_fourpt2@fivept1_fivept2,six
one
two
three
fourpt1_fourpt2
fivept1_fivept2
six
```

Element zero of `BASH_REMATCH` contains the entire match; the remaining elements contain the individual capture groups, from the left.

Alternatively, you can use `read` to split first on `@`, then again to split the two halves using `_` and `,` as appropriate.

```
$ IFS="@" read -r first second <<< "$line"
$ IFS=_ read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 <<< "$first"
$ IFS=, read -r f5 f6 <<< "$second"
```

Because the second call to read only has 4 arguments, `f4` will contain whatever follows the 3rd `_`, without any further field splitting on additional `_`s.

---

A similar regular expression and two-level splitting scheme can be used in a language that supports more efficient iteration over the contents of a file, which (as Nahuel Fouilleul points out) `bash` doesn't do very quickly. (`read` reads its input byte-by-byte, rather than reading entire chunks at once, to avoid reading more bytes than necessary to consume exactly one line of input.)

Comment: You would still iterate over the file line-by-line (which I guess I should include in the answer).

Comment: I meant: what if you have to repeat that transformation 5000 times *per line*? I'm trying to avoid the repetition of the regexp. The one liner shown in the question is easier and cleaner than this two liner :-(

Comment: The *line* has 5000 different fields? I would definitely move to a different langauge; `bash` isn't meant for that kind of data processing! You can split on *all* `_`, then rejoin whatever trailing parts were split. (Using Python as an example,  something like `fields = line.split('_'); fields[5000] = '_'.join(fields[5001:])`)

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than 1 time a field with @.*_.*_....,
You can try this awk :

```
echo "data1_data2@d_a_t_a_17,data3_data4@d_a_t_a_5,data6_data7" |
awk '
{
i = split ( $0 , a , "_" )
for ( j = 1 ; j <= i ; j++ )
  if ( a[j] !~ /@/ )
    print "d" ++k "==\"" a[j] "\""
  else
    {
      split ( a[j] , b , "@" )
      print "d" ++k "==\"" b[1] "\""
      sub ( ".*@" , "" , a[j] )
      while ( a[j] !~ "," )
        {
          c = c a[j] "_"
          j++
        }
        split ( a[j] , b , "," )
        c = c b[1]
        print "d" ++k "==\"" c "\""
        a[j] = b[2]
        j--
        c = ""
    }
}'
```